# DB2 in AS400 date format configuration using spring

Tags: date, spring-jdbc, db2-400

I'm trying to get a date after 12-31-2039 in DB2 but it always returns null. My project uses spring JDBC configured with jt400.jar JDBC driver. How can I resolve this problem? Follows my config at spring:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="br.com.mycompany.persistence.driver.SecuredAS400JDBC">
    <property name="serverName"     value="${br.com.mycompany.dao.jdbc.server}" />
    <property name="databaseName"   value="${br.com.mycompany.dao.jdbc.database}" />
    <property name="libraries"      value="${br.com.mycompany.dao.jdbc.database}" />
    <property name="user"           value="${br.com.mycompany.dao.jdbc.username}" />
    <property name="password"       value="${br.com.mycompany.dao.jdbc.password}" />
    <property name="dataTruncation" value="false" />
    <property name="naming" value="sql" />
    <property name="errors" value="full" />
    <property name="trace" value="false" />
    <property name="prompt" value="false" />
</bean>
```

And here is my resultset operation:

```
private static final class rowMapperDTO implements RowMapper<AcionamentoFaixa> {

    public AcionamentoFaixa mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {

        AcionamentoFaixa obj = new  AcionamentoFaixa();         
        obj.setDe(rs.getDate(4));
        obj.setAte(rs.getDate(5));

        return obj;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer at IBM Toolbox Java official documentation: http://www-03.ibm.com/systems/power/software/i/toolbox/faq/jdbc.html#faqB5

> "The Toolbox JDBC driver uses the date format that is set up as the
>   default on the IBM i system. This default is usually set to "mdy"
>   which only supports dates between 1940 and 2039. You can override the date format by specifying the "**date format**" property when opening the JDBC connection. The best choice is "**iso**", which supports a full four-digit date."

So, I tried to config the bean with the property dateFormat to iso and it works perfectly!

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="br.com.mycompany.persistence.driver.SecuredAS400JDBC">
    <property name="serverName"     value="${br.com.mycompany.dao.jdbc.server}" />
    <property name="databaseName"   value="${br.com.mycompany.dao.jdbc.database}" />
    <property name="libraries"      value="${br.com.mycompany.dao.jdbc.database}" />
    <property name="user"           value="${br.com.mycompany.dao.jdbc.username}" />
    <property name="password"       value="${br.com.mycompany.dao.jdbc.password}" />
    <property name="dataTruncation" value="false" />
    <property name="naming" value="sql" />
    <property name="errors" value="full" />
    <property name="trace" value="false" />
    <property name="prompt" value="false" />
    <property name="dateFormat" value="iso" />
</bean>
```